# trying to centre my background video when using media query

Tags: html, css, video, media-queries, html5-video

is this impossible to do or something? been working all morning to try and position my video to the centre or try and change the size of the video to small so it can fit at least the key parts of the video so the user can see it on their mobile. What is the best solution to this? I've been researching a lot and can't find any help on this and makes me wonder maybe this is too much to ask for in CSS? unless there is another alternative... please let me know! many thanks!

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #333;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.para {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: auto 10px;;
}

.v-header {
    height: 99vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
}

#jsc {
/*display: none;*/
}

.container {
    max-width: 960px;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.container h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

section {
    display: flex;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#heading {
    font-family: 'Coiny', cursive;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: none;
}

.header-overlay {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #225470;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.65;
}

.header-content {
    z-index: 2;
}

.header-content .jsc {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.header-content .jsc {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.btn {
    background: #34b3a0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    text-decoration: none;
}


@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { 

    #jsc {
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
    }

    .fullscreen-video-wrap {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        right: 100px;
    }
}
```

```
        <div class="fullscreen-video-wrap">

    <video src="seaturtle.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="true"></video>

        </div>

    <div class="header-overlay"></div>  
    <div class="header-content">

        <img id="jsc" src="jscc.png">
        <h3 id="heading">Personal Training</h3>
             <a href="#" class="btn">Contact Me</a>
    </div>  

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your "head" tag. This will automatically resize your video according to the device width.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
    video {
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
    }
 </style>
 </head>
```